# how to configure the DBeaver and Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, dbeaver

I am very new to DBeaver. From forum i got to know that driver need to update for cassandra 3+ to work with DBeaver. 
https://github.com/serge-rider/dbeaver/issues/167
I downloaded this new driver but unable to set the class path. Can anyone help me on this.Below is the current config i did for driver and cassandra.

[image]

Comment: Now its working with below config.                                                    cassandra-jdbc-driver:
http://www.dbschema.com/cassandra-jdbc-driver.html
Driver Information :
Driver Name:   User Friendly Name
Driver Type:   Generic
Java Driver Class:  com.dbschema.CassandraJdbcDriver
URL:   jdbc:cassandra://{host}[:{port}]/{database}
Required File(s):  cassandra-driver.jar
Default Port:  9042
Library File:  cassandrajdbc1.1

Comment: could you please write the steps ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect to Cassandra with Dbeaver Community edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027126/how-do-i-connect-to-cassandra-with-dbeaver-community-edition)

Answer (score 13):

As I had some problems finding Cassandra driver after DBeaver install, I went through another way:

- Cloned [this GitHub project](https://github.com/adejanovski/cassandra-jdbc-wrapper)
- Built the jar file (mvn package)
- Added this jar file to the Driver Manager configuration, using the JDBC Class Name and JDBC URL values as described at project README:

[image]

Comment: I used fat jar as mentioned in git project and it could connect to cassandra showing all keyspaces and their tables. But when it comes to showing data, there is error as, "Read data 'table_name' has encountered problem"

Comment: To assist others with copy&paste, the Class Name is `org.apache.cassandra2.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver` and the URL Template is `jdbc:cassandra://{host}[:{port}]/{database}`.

Comment: The jar file is available from the [releases](https://github.com/adejanovski/cassandra-jdbc-wrapper/releases) page so you don't have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 12):

Download and use dbeaver enterprise edition (for free as well, not open source though) which includes cassandra driver by default.

Comment: dbeaver enterprise is not free since July 2017 :(

Answer (score 12):

Tested on DBeaver Community Edition 7.3.0.202011292131

1. Go to https://downloads.datastax.com/#odbc-jdbc-drivers
2. Select Simba JDBC Driver for Apache Cassandra
3. Open DBeaver
4. Database > Driver Manager
5. New
   [image: [![preview][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHzRY.png]

6. Do not fill Class Name manually, after `Add file` click `Find Class` and select.

Comment: that one worked for me. i only had to add a Connection properties: Under "Driver Properties", new, AuthMech set to 1

Comment: AuthMech=1 does the trick

Comment: I think this answer is defunct now. The download at https://downloads.datastax.com/#odbc-jdbc-drivers apears to only contain ODBC drivers now. There is no option that mentions "Simba".

Answer (score -2):

Here is another solution you can use [trial drivers](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/cassandra/jdbc/download/) and way to configure:

https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/cassandra-jdbc-dbvr.rst

Comment: The trial is limited to 30 days.