# How to connect Cassandra running on DCOS from dbeaver

Tags: cassandra, mesos, dcos, dbeaver

How to connect Cassandra cluster that is running on DCOS, through DBeaver/Devcenter.

Answer (score 2):

To connect to Cassandra you need to get at least one node. You can do it by asking dcos for all cassandra nodes:

```
$ dcos cassandra --name=<service-name> connection

{
  "address": [
    "10.0.0.47:9042",
    "10.0.0.50:9042",
    "10.0.0.49:9042"
  ],
  "dns": [
     "node-0.cassandra.mesos:9042",
     "node-1.cassandra.mesos:9042",
     "node-2.cassandra.mesos:9042"
  ]
}
```

The you can use this IPs and ports to connect.

- [how to configure the DBeaver and Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458880/how-to-configure-the-dbeaver-and-cassandra)
- https://github.com/mesosphere/dcos-cassandra-service/blob/master/docs/connecting-clients.md

Comment: The address that you mentioned are private that, which are not accessible.

Comment: In this case you should run one Cassandra node on public Mesos Agent or deploy some kind of proxy to access private nodes.

Comment: Can you elaborate this ?How do i Set the public mesos agent as the master.