# How do I configure the Twig JDBC driver in DbVisualizer to connect to a Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-20.04, dbvisualizer

I have an [Ubuntu 20.04.5](https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/) install which has a Cassandra database which I want to connect to with [DbVisualizer v14.0.1](https://www.dbvis.com/download/) using the [Cassandra Twig driver](https://www.micromux.com/development-projects/cassandra-twig-jdbc/) (for reasons best known to my organisation).

I have [installed DbVis](https://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG100/Installing#Installing-InstallationNotesforDEBarchives(Linux)) and downloaded the [cassandra-twig-jdbc-3.0.1.jar](https://github.com/esarjeant/twig/releases/download/3.0.1-2/cassandra-twig-jdbc-3.0.1.jar) driver, [started DbVis](https://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG100/Starting+DbVisualizer) with the free version.

I have installed the driver successfully, providing the URL format as `jdbc:cassandra://<server>:<port>/<database>` [specified by the Cassandra docs](https://www.micromux.com/development-projects/cassandra-twig-jdbc/), and named it 'Cassandra':
[image: driver manager screenhot]

I am now trying to create a database connection, for which the [documentation states there is a wizard](https://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG100/Creating+a+Connection+-+basics#CreatingaConnection-basics-UsingtheConnectionWizard), however I cannot find that.

Going with a [manual connection](https://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG100/Creating+a+Connection+-+basics#CreatingaConnection-basics-SettingUpaConnectionManually), I do not see the Database Connection panel described by the documentation, I just get a driver selection:
[image]

If I select the 'Cassandra' driver I don't get a 'Database URL' field:
[image: database connection]

Clicking 'Connect' fails - how can I define the connection URL for my local database?

Answer (score 2):

Open **Tools->Driver Manager** and choose the **Cassandra DataStax** driver entry. In the right pane click the **Start Download** link. Once ready, close the dialog. In the main window and in the Databases tab, click to create a new database connection and choose **Cassandra DataStax**. Now you can choose Database URL.

Answer (score 0):

The first step where you have installed the Twig driver in DBVisualizer, that's where you configure the URL.

In your screenshot, you have configured it with:

```
jdbc:cassandra://<server>:<port>/<database>
```

You should instead populate it with details of your cluster. For example, for this cluster:

- contact point IP - `10.1.2.3`
- client port - `9042`
- keyspace name - `mykeyspace`

the corresponding JDBC URL is:

```
jdbc:cassandra://10.1.2.3:9042/mykeyspace
```

I haven't written instructions specifically for DBVisualizer but if you're interested, I've written one for DBeaver in this post -- [How do I connect to Cassandra with Dbeaver Community edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027126/). Cheers!