# How can I install Apache Cassandra GUI in Ubuntu?

Tags: cassandra

I have installed Cassandra on my Ubuntu server. Now I want to access it in a browser (something like PHPMyAdmin for MySQL). How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra doesn't come with a graphical interface. You will need to install clients from third parties.

Here are some of the popular clients:

- [**DataStax DevCenter**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/developer/devcenter/doc/devcenter/dcAbout.html) is a free visual schema and query IDE for developers and administrators looking to run CQL statements against a Cassandra cluster. The last version was released in 2016 but it is still available to download from the [DataStax Downloads](https://downloads.datastax.com/#devcenter) site.
- **[DataStax Studio](https://docs.datastax.com/en/studio/docs/aboutStudio.html)** is an interactive developer tool for CQL, SparkSQL and DSE Graph. Studio can connect to clusters running [DataStax Enterprise](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) (not open-source Apache Cassandra).

You can also connect to a Cassandra cluster from RDBMS clients using the [Simba JDBC driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/driver-matrix/docs/install-simba-drivers.html). I have previously written instructions for the following clients:

- [DBeaver community edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027126/)
- [TablePlus](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320660/)
- [Pentaho Data Integration](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320664/) (PDI)

Finally, we (the Cassandra community) maintain a list of tools in the [Ecosystem](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/ecosystem.html) section of the official [Apache Cassandra website](https://cassandra.apache.org/) if you're interested in finding out what else is available. [Anant](https://anant.us/) also maintain a list at [cassandra.tools](https://cassandra.tools/). Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!