# Timeout error when accessing Cassandra from Dbeaver

Tags: jdbc, cassandra, dbeaver

I followed the instructions [here](https://javaresolutions.blogspot.com/2018/04/opensource-db-ui-tool-for-cassandra-db.html) - to get DBeaver Community (Ver 23.0) working with Cassandra.
For small tables, it works ok, but for larger ones, it times out after 2 seconds with the error `SQL Error: Query timed out after PT2S`.  I can't find where this 2 second timeout is defined in DBeaver. Most of the timeout fields in the config are set to 0, meaning no timeout, although I did play with them to see if they'd make a difference.
How do I increase this timeout?  Or is there a different JDBC driver I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the JDBC driver in the link you provided so I don't know how to configure it to increase the timeout.

However, I've previously documented the instructions in [How do I connect to Cassandra with Dbeaver Community edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027126/) using the **Simba JDBC Driver for Apache Cassandra**.

However, it appears that [Simba has been acquired by insightsoftware](https://mobile.twitter.com/Mag_SW/status/1578414884965974019) so the driver might not be available for free download anymore. In any case, details on the JDBC driver is [available here](https://insightsoftware.com/drivers/cassandra-odbc-jdbc/). Cheers!

**[EDIT]** We are sorting a few things out in the background. If you give us a few days, we think we'll have the driver available for free again.

Comment: Any update on how to get the driver for free?

Comment: Thanks for the ping. I'm trying to find out what's happening with our agreement with Simba/insightsoftware. I'll post an update mid next week at the latest. Feel free to ping me here again if you don't hear from me. Thanks for your patience. Cheers!

Comment: Just another ping

Comment: @PeterKronenberg can we have a quick chat on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/253326? 

Comment: I posted on the chat.  Not sure it'll work out with the time difference :-)