# Cant find driver class in dbeaver for Apache Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, dbeaver

I need to add Cassandra as a driver in DBeaver and have been using the answer from Erick Ramirez in this post [How do I connect to Cassandra with Dbeaver Community edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69027126/how-do-i-connect-to-cassandra-with-dbeaver-community-edition/69028505#69028505) as reference for 2 years with no problems at all.

I got a new computer and this time I got a problem with DBeaver not identifying the driver class after I select the jar file.

I followed these steps:
Driver manager > New > Libraries > Add File > Select jar file > Find Class

[class box is empty after clicking Find Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSN83.png)

it should appear `com.simba.cassandra.jdbc42.Driver`.

JDCB Apache Cassandra is not provided by DataStax anymore, but I got the file from the wayback machine https://web.archive.org/web/20230104184941/https://downloads.datastax.com/#odbc-jdbc-drivers.

Does anyone have a clue as to why this is happening and if there's a solution?

I haven't found any material on this issue so I dont know where to start.

I'm using Dbeaver Community Edition 23.3.2, on Windows 11 Home Single Language x64.

---

UPDATE 1:
I went to my old computer which dbeaver cassandra works just fine, so I downloaded the same version of DBeaver(23.2.2) in my new computer, also transferred the same .jar file, still results in the same error.

It seems this is a problem with my new computer. (update 2: it wasn't, tried in three different machines)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way around through these steps:

1. Driver Manager > New
2. Define a name for the database
3. Libraries > Add File > Select Jar file
4. OK(Save the incomplete database)
5. Driver Manager
6. Double click on the newly created database
7. Libraries > Find Class > Select driver class
8. OK
9. Celebrate

The initial problem is contoured, but I issued the bug in DBeaver github repo https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/22430

Comment: Nice! Glad you figured it out.